# Convert 3/5 dimensional array to RGB images

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I use a numpy.ndarray to represent a 3D gesture sequence provided by a Kinect-like sensor.

The relevant dimensions to represent the gesture are:

```
(x, y, z, j, t)
```

where:

- x is the x position channel
- y is the y position channel
- z is the z position channel
- j is the index of the joint in the (kinect-like) body skeleton
- t is the time index

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Currently, however, my array is not stored as a 5d-array, but as a 3d-array:

```
gesture.shape = (time, joint, 3)
```

(where 3 = 1 + 1 + 1, for x, y and z, and where time=100 and joint=25).

My goal is to produce a RGB image, using 2 of the 5 array axes as the image axes, and the 3 (= 5 minus the 2 already used as image axes) remaining array axes as the (r,g,b) value of each pixel.

```
R=z, G=j, B=t  --- Ax1=x, Ax2=y
R=y, G=j, B=t  --- Ax1=x, Ax2=z
R=y, G=z, B=t  --- Ax1=x, Ax2=j
R=y, G=z, B=j  --- Ax1=x, Ax2=t
R=x, G=j, B=t  --- Ax1=y, Ax2=z
R=x, G=z, B=t  --- Ax1=y, Ax2=j
R=x, G=z, B=j  --- Ax1=y, Ax2=t
R=x, G=y, B=t  --- Ax1=z, Ax2=j
R=x, G=y, B=j  --- Ax1=z, Ax2=t
R=x, G=y, B=z  --- Ax1=j, Ax2=t
```

This seems easy to do, however I did not succeed in shaping or indexing my 3d array correctly to produce these images.

What should I do?

Comment: To clarify, you want to transform `gesture` to the shape (M, 5), where M is the number of observations, and the entries in M are: R, G, B, J, and T?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I want to (1) transform `gesture` to the shape (M,5), where M is the number of observations, and the entries in M are: R, G, B, J, and T, and (2) plot this 5d tensor as a matplotlib rgb image.